# Error al mostrar datos de la base de datos mySQL

Tags: php, html, visual-studio, wampserver

tengo un error que me impide mostrar lo que hay en mi base de datos mySQL. Estoy utilizando wampserver.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu segunda imagen, la línea 4, no será algo así: `$resultado = ConectarBD()->query('select * from users');`

Comment: Quizás deberías invocar la función ConectarDB() en tu index.php (Creo que eso es lo que te está indicando también Yussef). Ten en cuenta que en dbConnect.php defines la función pero parece que no se llama y en index.php no asignas la variable $cnx de ahí que te aparezca ese mensaje con null. Por otro lado, por favor, procura incluir tu código en forma de texto formateado y no como imágenes cuando postees una pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema en tu código es que la conexión **es retornada** desde la función `ConectarBD()`, pero tú asumes que la tendrás disponible sólo con incluir el archivo. Pero no funciona así. La conexión se crea dentro de la función y no la tendrás hasta que no llames a esa función que la crea. Otra cosa sería si estuvieras en el contexto de una clase y la conexión fuese una propiedad de dicha clase, pero no nos metamos en eso.

El problema actual tiene dos soluciones posibles:

#### Si usarás la conexión una sola vez en ese ámbito

Puedes hacer una llamada directa, como sugiere @Yussef en su comentario y punto final:

```
$resultado = ConectarBD()->query('select * from users');
```

#### Si usarás la conexión varias veces en ese ámbito

En ese caso, no conviene hacer una llamada directa a `ConectarBD()` cada vez, porque estarías conectando una y ooootra vez, afectando el rendimiento, porque la conexión supone un costo. En ese caso deberías guardar una referencia a la conexión en ese ámbito, para seguir usándola. Por ejemplo:

```
$mysqli=ConectarBD();

$users=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$cities=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cities");
$employees=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM employees");
// etc ...
```

No vendría mal una lectura al apartado [**Ámbito de las variables**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php) en el Manual de PHP.